# Best way to copy files from a hard disk with no OS

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, partitioning, usb-installation, data-loss

I have a 1 TB hard disk with no OS in it. What will be the best way to copy files to an external hdd from unaffected partitions?

I have a Live Windows USB. I learnt that you can boot into Command Promt and open Notebook.exe and from Open files, you can send data to an external drive.

I am considering giving Ubuntu a chance here. I plan to install Ubuntu on the partition where Windows used to be. Now will I be able to boot into Ubuntu and simply copy files from other partitions into the external hdd?

My internal HDD is of course of NTFS type.

Now I cannot install Windows to my HDD because if I delete the partition which used to be C:/, a chunk of unallocated space is created in the middle of the memory segment. And in my experience, I have seen that Windows installation media can only create a new volume at the beginning or at the end of the space. The error I get is Windows can't create a partition.

Please let me know if it is possible to install Ubuntu there and access the data at the other partitions and safely copy them to external hdd.

I have heard about ntfs-3g and not sure how it works. But to even go there, I have to be able to install Ubuntu in the first place.

I was using Windows 10 before, if it matters.

Comment: If you can create an Ubuntu live USB using another computer and boot this computer from the live USB, you can copy your files into an external hard drive.

Comment: @user68186 are you sure about it?

Comment: Yes, boot a OS in 'live' mode (eg. Ubuntu install media using the 'try Ubuntu' option; https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0) then `mount` your hdd/ssd & copy files to an external drive, network drive etc.  @user68186 is correct  (though if your *filesystem* is in an unclean (eg. hibernated) state with parts of it in hibernate file) that will be extremely difficult)

Comment: @guiverc is correct. If the the partitions are dirty, that is either hibernated or improperly shutdown, you will run into problems.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, will do this. Only the Windows partition is wasted and I did not keep any other files in it. Actually the OS is still there, but the recovery volume and the boot volume is gone and can't repair it with Windows USB. So will try this.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks, will do this. Only the Windows partition is wasted and I did not keep any other files in it. Actually the OS is still there, but the recovery volume and the boot volume is gone and can't repair it with Windows USB. So will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could flip internal and external HDD. Remove your internal HDD out of your PC and use it as an external HDD and your other HDD as an internal HDD. If you current external HDD is empty you can safely boot it with Windows or Ubuntu and use your new OS to access your old data, for this you could buy an Adapter SATA to USB (around six euros) and use your current internal HDD as an external HDD. Or you could try to use the case of your external HDD.

There are probably some great youtube video's on how to replace a HDD if you've never done this before. Hope this works and is a safe solution, have a nice day!